# remove all HTML when embedding blocks in node template

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I'm embedding two blocks inside a node using something like:

```
<?php

 $block = block_load('views', 'principles-block');      
 $output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
 print $output; 

?>
```

My problem is that $output comes with a whole bunch of html tags and css classes that I wish to completely remove.

```
<div id="block-views-principles-block" class="block block-views contextual-links-region">

    <h2>Principles</h2>
    <div class="contextual-links-wrapper">
    <ul class="contextual-links">
        <li class="block-configure first last"><a href="siteurl/fpis/admin/structure/block/manage/views/principles-block/configure?destination=node/11">Configure</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="view view-principles view-id-principles view-display-id-block view-dom-id-499e1dbfd506d4a550f3b3645bc8a5bf">
    </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I just want to print the fields in plain text and be able to add HTML tags and CSS classes that I choose in the template. Is this possible? I've tried Fences and Semantic Views with no success.

Comment: Override the block template with your own. [Theming blocks individually, by region, or by module](https://www.drupal.org/node/104319)